# Confusing routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I know this is a newbie question, but I haven't seen an explanation and I'd like one.

What exactly does it mean when Rails issues a routing error like this:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"library_imports", :library_id=>#<Library id: 1, ...
```

What puzzles me is that the message itself shows that my request is being routed to the `show` action of the `library_imports` controller.  How does that happen if the request URL didn't match any routes?

For the sake of completeness, the URL I'm hitting that results in this error is:

```
http://localhost:3000/libraries/2/library_imports
```

which *should* map to the "index" action, not "show".

The relevant part of `config/routes.rb` is:

```
Import::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :libraries do
    resources :library_imports
  end
```

And the pertinent portion of `rake routes` output is:

```
    library_library_imports GET    /libraries/:library_id/library_imports(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"library_imports"}
                            POST   /libraries/:library_id/library_imports(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"library_imports"}
 new_library_library_import GET    /libraries/:library_id/library_imports/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"library_imports"}
edit_library_library_import GET    /libraries/:library_id/library_imports/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"library_imports"}
     library_library_import GET    /libraries/:library_id/library_imports/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"library_imports"}
                            PUT    /libraries/:library_id/library_imports/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"library_imports"}
                            DELETE /libraries/:library_id/library_imports/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"library_imports"}
```

Comment: can you put the actual route you were trying to hit and the relevant bit of the routes.rb file? I've seen in the past that the show seems to be the default route for member routes for the cases when I'm trying to use a route that's broken. One thing that gets me sometimes is using a GET/POST/PUT wrongly...meaning it's a GET and I mistakenly try to use a POST.

Comment: I'll add some specifics to my question, but the answer I'm looking for is more general than this particular instance: i.e. in general how can Rails determine an action and a controller from a URL while simultaneously saying it can't route the request?

Comment: I've often seen the show action as the default route in these cases but I don't know why this happens in some case and not in others. I'm sorry I can't be more helpful on this...

Comment: Update: I found the problem that caused this particular error.  In the view for library_imports#index I had a 'destroy' link that was using library_library_import_path(@library) instead of 'library_library_import_path

Comment: I meant, instead of library_library_import_path(@library, @library_import).  So there certainly was a routing error in there somewhere.  I have no idea why Rails thought the "show" action was involved though.  I find the error confusing -- even misleading. Anyway, I'm leaving the question open for answers in case anybody can help me understand what Rails is doing here.

Comment: What exact version of rails is this? I've seen that with 3.0.0, but >=3.0.7 appears to have fixed it for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading for what it doesn't say, rather than what it says. There is indeed no route that can be constructed from `:controller => :library_imports, :action => :show, :library_id => @library`, because that hash omits the required `:id` parameter.

It might be less confusing if there were some hint, like `(did you leave out a required parameter?`).

It's also useful to note that this error is generated (I believe) in the `url_for` helper, not in the dispatcher. So the request is not actually being routed at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply zetetic.  It's taken me several days of thinking about it, but I guess it makes some sense to me now.  With that understanding, the message is more helpful, and your answer makes sense to me now too.

Comment: The named path library_library_import_path can route to :show or :delete depending on the request method used.  I was using it to construct a "delete" link.  Evidently Rails assumes that it will be involved in a :show action.  So it all makes much more sense now, but that error message could certainly be improved upon.